# Short French podcast used to transcribe?

Tags: ressources, apprentissage, radio

I need a good resource to train my listening comprehension of French language. I decide to find some podcasts of 2-3 minutes which is appropriate for transcribing. Now I am a beginner and newsinslowfrench is quite appropriate for me. But since I need to listen to normal speed French eventually, I need to gradually add some materials to transcribe, something similar to Scientific American 60 Seconds in English.

I googled but something called 1 minute French isn't appropriate. I need something completely in French, including but not necessarily restricted to news.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are dozens of exercises [here](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/category/listening/). They include a transcript, so you can listen and try transcribing yourself, then compare what you've done to the official version.

Bon courage !

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! Eh, and how can I make the question into a community wiki since it's not a question with only one *correct* answer.

Comment: @FrankScience https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Answer (score 1):

Hundreds of videos [here](https://www.youtube.com/user/Unisciel/videos), mostly on physics-related topics and most of them just a few minutes long.